# Primefaces Adamantium autoComplete styling is messed up

Tags: css, user-interface, jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I have a p:autoComplete component in my view that is capable of accepting multiple values, like so:

```jsf
<p:autoComplete
    id="typesList"
    value="#{bean.types}"
    completeMethod="#{bean.typeLookup}"
    var="type"
    itemLabel="#{type.name}"
    itemValue="#{type}"
    queryDelay="300"
    maxResults="5"
    converter="typeConverter"
    dropdown="true"
    multiple="true">
    ...select and unselect ajax events...
</p:autoComplete>
```

I have purchased and am using the Primefaces Adamantium theme. Have not added any style customizations to the autoComplete component, yet this is how it looks:
[image]

As you can see, the dropdown arrow button is rendered below the actual textbox, for some reason. If I enter a lot of values, the textbox and the button both expand, but one always stays above the other. If I inspect the elements, I see the following style classes on the textbox:

```
ui-autocomplete-multiple-container ui-widget ui-inputfield ui-state-default ui-corner-all
```

And the following on the down arrow button:

```
ui-autocomplete-dropdown ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-right ui-button-icon-only
```

I've inspected each style class individually and I don't see anything that could be causing the issue. All of them are out-of-the-box, I haven't modified them in any way. Taking out one, many or all of the above style classes does not change anything. The button still appears below the textbox. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What is the wrapper/ parent of this `p:autocomplete` ?

Comment: does it work with the normal default theme? Do you have the latest of that theme? Do you have the latest PF?

Comment: @JalalSordo This is the parent hierarchy:
form -> wizard -> tab -> panel -> panelGrid
All but panelGrid use default styling, panelGrid is using ui-panelgrid-blank.

Comment: you mean it's directly wrapped by body tag ?

Comment: @Kukeltje I'm using PF 6.0. The Adamantium showcase doesn't have the multiple value autoComplete so I'm not sure if it works with default settings. Any other way I could check that?

Comment: @JalalSordo I'm not entirely sure what that means but yes, the form is wrapped by a body tag.

Comment: your comment just got edited that's why I asked that, it was "This is the parent hierarchy."

Comment: In order to make sure it's a ui bug, you will need to take the autocomplete outside of all the wrappers and put it directly under the form tag, and tell me the results after you do that.

Comment: And also try without the Adamantium theme... That is what I suggested...

Comment: @JalalSordo Yes sorry, I pressed Enter by accident a couple of times so had to edit the comment. I tried putting the autoComplete tag directly under the form, with no change in the result. There is no styling on the form either.

Comment: @Kukeltje I have used the autoComplete component without the Adamantium theme before and it has rendered correctly. Since the new project I'm working on is built entirely on Adamantium, I can't not use it.

Comment: I see, did you try another browser,removing the converter ?

Comment: @JalalSordo Removed converter, tried in Firefox. No change.

Comment: Since it is theme related, inspect the css. And since it is a commercial theme, file an issue... We cannot help, since 99.5% of us don't have that theme and the ones that do are either not on SO or have nourge to help.

Comment: Did you test without enabling the multiple attribute, because they don't have a demo for that in the official showcase of Primefaces Adamantium.

Comment: Yes I've used it without the multiple attribute, and it works fine. But for this particular component I need multiple values, so I cannot avoid it. And yes, I will file an issue. Thanks for the help, Jalal and Kukeltje.

Comment: So it's a ui bug, when multiple attribute is enabled, exactly, just file an issue.

Comment: Aha, as it turns out someone has already filed an issue for this and it seems to have been fixed. https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1478 Now I just need to figure out how to get it!